# Trimming empty elements off end of ByteArray

Tags: kotlin

I'm looking for a way of truncating a ByteArray without creating copies. I.e. I want to minimize memory allocations.

Currently the extension function looks like this but it returns a copy of the ByteArray.

```
companion object {
    private fun ByteArray.truncateAtZero(): ByteArray {
        val indexOfZero = this.indexOf(0.toByte())
        return if (indexOfZero != -1) {
            this.copyOfRange(0, indexOfZero)
        } else {
            this
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You cannot. The size of a `ByteArray` must not change. How about using a `ByteBuffer` instead (JVM only)? You can `slice` a `ByteBuffer` without copying its contents.

Comment: Looks like the UsbDeviceConnection class only takes Byte[]:

public int bulkTransfer(UsbEndpoint endpoint, byte[] buffer, int length, int timeout)

Comment: It looks like it also takes a `length` parameter. So if your goal is to call that method, just pass in a `length` smaller than `buffer.length` (more specifically, `indexOfZero`, when it is not negative). This "truncates" the array as far as `bulkTransfer` is concerned.